# IntelliJ IDEA code completion doesn't show JPA '@Id' import

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete

`IntelliJ IDEA` doesn't show the import assistance when typing `@Id`, but then later asks if you want to import it. Not a big issue as such but I don't understand why this behavior and can anything be done to fix this.

Here are the screen shots of what I am trying to say,

1. When I type `@Id` it shows suggestions like `Override` and so on but no `Id` suggestion.

[image]

2. And now as a workaround, I have to leave it as it is, and then import it as suggested,

[image]

Can somebody please help me out here, I am frequent user of `Eclipse` and was trying out `IntelliJ`

Comment: try: **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: thank you for the reply, I tried but it didn't work out

Comment: Another workaround: Check "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" in the settings. It's still annoying though. Maybe you should create bugreport on youtrack.jetbrains.com, which could be copy/paste of this question. If you do, share a link to it, so I can watch it/vote for it as this issue has bothered me for some time too.

Comment: yeah sounds good, I will create a bug and share a link.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt and other users here is the bug link, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147762

Comment: Thanks, I just voted for it, let's see if/when it gets fixed :)

Comment: Just so others know, in the ticket above mentioned, suggested to use Ctrl+Space as a workaround